# Filter grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
 DATE                  MEAN    SUM  MAX MIN SAISON JAHR
1 1995-09-01 00:00:00 2.370833 56.9 7.4   0      S 1995
2 1995-09-01 01:00:00 2.225000 53.4 7.4   0      S 1995
3 1995-09-01 02:00:00 2.091667 50.2 7.4   0      S 1995
4 1995-09-01 03:00:00 1.929167 46.3 7.4   0      S 1995
5 1995-09-01 04:00:00 1.745833 41.9 7.4   0      S 1995
6 1995-09-01 05:00:00 1.558333 37.4 7.4   0      S 1995
....
```

With the dplyr package I am able to extract the highest SUM for every SAISON and JAHR:

```
group_by(.data = dataframe,JAHR,SAISON)
summarise(gJahrSAISON_24, hoechsterNiederschlag = max(SUM))
```

Do you have any idea how to extract the ten(!) highest sums for every JAHR and SAISON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice` with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(JAHR, SAISON) %>%
  arrange(desc(SUM)) %>%
  slice(1:10)
```

Or `filter` with `min_rank/dense_rank`

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(JAHR, SAISON) %>%
    filter(dense_rank(SUM)<=10)
```

Similar options using `data.table` are

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[order(-SUM), .SD[1:10], by = .(JAHR, SAISON)]
```

Or

```
 setDT(df1)[, .SD[frank(SUM, ties.method='first') <=10], by = .(JAHR, SAISON)]
```

Or using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select * from df1 i
        where rowid in
          (select rowid from df1 
              where JAHR = i.JAHR and SAISON=i.SAISON
              order by SUM desc
              limit 10)
 order by i.JAHR, i.SAISON, i.SUM desc')
```

Or with `base R`

```
df1[with(df1, ave(SUM, SAISON, JAHR, FUN=function(x)
                    rank(-x, ties.method='first'))<=10),]
```